# c includes, preventing redundant code

Tags: c, include, refactoring, duplicates, header-files

If I have a c project where my main program needs file1 and file2 but file2 also needs file1. Is there a way I can get around including file2 in both main and file1? If I have an include guard, will this prevent file1.c from being added twice?

```
//file1.h
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

void func1(void);
#endif
```

--

```
//file1.c
#include "file1.h"
void func1(void) {
  ..do something
}
```

--

```
//file2.h
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

void func2(void);
#endif
```

--

```
//file2.c
#include "file2.h"
#include "file1.h"

void func2(void) {
  ..do something
  func1();
}
```

--

```
//main.c
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main(void) {
  func1();
  func2();

  return 0;
}
```

-- Since file2 includes file1, can I do this? will it prevent repetition of file1 code?

```
//main.c (alternate)
#include "file2.h"

int main(void) {
  func1();
  func2();

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not too concerned about problems arising if file2 decides to no longer include file1 in the future. I'm much more concerned with wasted space.

What I'd like to know is A: does the include guard prevent the code duplication and if so, there is no additional space used by including file1 in both main.c and file2.c. B: in the case that extra space is being used, will my alternate main.c work?

Comment: But the *header file* `file2.h` doesn't include `file1.h`? Also, that repetition you're worried about will not manifest itself in the resulting program executable, it will be a *single* entry in the compilers internal tables, that's all.

Comment: `If I have an include guard, will this prevent file1.c from being added twice?`  Not sure what you mean by this...  Never `#include` a source file.  If you have an "include guard" in a header file, it prevents the contents of the header file from be defined/included multiple times.

Comment: Include guards only prevent the same header to be included multiple times in the same [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (i.e. source file).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so you're saying if I move the include file1.h from file2.c to file1.h then file2.h basically declares file1.h to be available for anything using file2.h?

Comment: @FiddlingBits this has to do with me not knowing exactly how/when the source file actually gets used. At some point when you include file1.h, the code from file1.c comes along for the ride (only if it's functions are used in the program?) So I'm worried that when I include file1.h twice, file1.c is also added twice.

Comment: @user3817250 Only if you `#include`d a source file, would it be added twice (or more), however, this would undoubtedly result in a compilation error.  Do you have access to a `.map` file?  It'll tell you how memory is used for your program.

Comment: @user3817250 your guards seem to be setup correctly. The general idea to follow is this: include in a file whatever is *needed* for that file to pass compilation when used in a translation unit. To that end you've done it right. `file2.h` references nothing in, and thereby needs nothing *from*, `file1.h`. So don't include it. `file2.c` refers to both its prototype info (`file2.h`) *and* refers to declarations provided in `file1.h` so include *both*. `main.c` refers to declarations in both `file1.h` and `file2.h`, ergo include *both*. Don't built assumptions into nested includes.

Comment: thanks for the help everyone. I feel like I'm getting a better understanding of it all. Gotta make sure I've got the best practices down before the projects start to grow. @FiddlingBits I never knew about the .map file, should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick explanation (with the note that all of this can be overwritten by people that know what they are doing):

First of all, two definitions: **declaration** is when you write down that something exists. For example, "`int foo();`" or "`struct bar;`". Note that we can't actually use this thing yet, we've just given it a name. As long as you declare them as the same thing, you can declare things as many times as you want! (variable declaration has its own rules).

Anything you want to use needs to be declared before you reference it.

**definition** is when you say what the declaration is. `int foo() {asdfadf;}` or `struct bar{int x;}`. Things can be (and often are) defined when they are declared, but not always.

In C, you must follow the One Definition Rule. Things can be declared as often as you like, but they can be only defined once per **translation unit** (defined in one sec). (in addition, function calls can only be declared once per entire executable).

There are very few things that need to be defined before you use them...other than variables, you only need to define a struct before you use it in a context where you need its size or access to its members.

What is a translation unit? It is all the files used to compile a single source file. Your header files aren't targeted for compilation. Only your .c files (called "source files") are. For each c file, we have the idea of a "translation unit", which is all the files that are used to compile that c file. The ultimate output of that code is a .o file. A .o files contains all the symbols required to run the code *defined* in that c++ file. So your c file and any files included are withing the header file. Note: not everything declared in the translation unit needs to be defined in it to get a valid .o file.

So what is in a header file? Well (in general) you have a few things:

- function declarations
- global definitions & declarations
- struct definitions & declarations

Basically, you have the bare bones declarations and definitions that need to be shared between the translation units. `#include` allows you to keep this in one shared file, rather than copying and pasting this code all over.

Your definitions can only happen once, so a include guard prevents that from being a problem. But if you only have declarations, you don't technically *need* and include guard. (You should still use them anyway, they can limit the cross-includes you do, as well as work as a guarantee against infinitely recursive inclusion). However, you do need to include all declarations relative to each translation unit, so you will most likely include it multiple times. THIS IS OK. At-least the declaration is in one file.

When you compile a .o file, the compiler checks that you followed the one definition rule, as well as all your syntax is correct. This is why you'll get these types of errors in "creating .o" steps of compilation.

So in your example, after we compile, we get file1.o (containing the definition of func1), file2.o (containing the definition of func2), and main.o (containing the definition of main). The next step is to **link** all these files together, using the **linker**. When we do, the compiler takes all these .o files, and makes sure that there is only one definition for each function symbol in the file. This is where the magic of letting main.o know what is in file1.o and file2.o happens: it resolves the "unresolved symbols" and detects when there are conflicting symbols.

Final Thought:

Keeping code short is kindof a misguided task. You want your code to be maintainable and readable, and making the code as short as possible is about the opposite of that. I can write a whole program on one line with only single letter alpha-numberic variables names, but no one would ever know what it did...what you want to avoid is code duplication in things like declarations. Maintaining a long list of #includes can become tricky, so it is often good to group related functions together (A good rule of thumb is that if I almost always use A and B together) then they should probably be in the same header file.

Another thing I occasionally (occasionally because it has some serious drawbacks) is to use a convenience header file:

```
//convience.h
#ifndef CONVIENIENCE_H
#define CONVIENIENCE_H
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#endif
```

The convenience header file only has other header files in it, which ensures that it NEVER contains code, which makes it a little easier to maintain, but still kindof a mess. Also note that if you do the include guards in file1 and file2, the convienience guard isn't nessisary, though it can (theoretically) speed up compilation.

Comment: `Keeping code short is kindof a misguided task` While I generally agree and prefer to write extremely verbose code. I'm trying to use as little space as possible because the device I'm working on has very little space.

Comment: @user3817250 Then you should be worried about the size of the executable, not the size of the source. The source could have the entire Illiad worth of comments and it would not effect the size of the executable. The same is true of #include statements.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have a single header where you can put both your functions func1() and func2().
Just include the header in different files.

Didn't get what you mean by code duplication.

```
//file1.h



extern void func1();
extern void func2();

//file1.c
#include<file1.h>
void func1()
{`
enter code here`
}


//file2.c
#include<file1.h>
void func2()
{
}

//main.c

#include <file1.h>

main()
{
func1();
func2();
}
```

Comment: By convention, and because it expands where the compiler is allowed to look for said header files, you should use quotes on user header files and angle brackets on system header files.